# How configure PHPUnit with XAMPP's MySQL on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, phpunit

I have trouble with running my test with XAMPP's MySQL and my Local MySQL. Whenever I run my test, the database connection is always on my Local MySQL not on XAMPP.

I have installed PHPUnit in my directory with composer.

I'm using PDO in my connection.

> ConfigDB.php

```
namespace App\Config;

use \PDO;

class ConfigDB
{
    private static $password = ''; //XAMPP has no password
    //private static $password = '******'; Local Machine MySQL password
    private static $username = 'root';
    private static $host     = '127.0.0.1';
    private static $database = 'tododb';
    private static $charSet  = 'utf8mb4';

    public function connect(): PDO
    {
        try {
            $dsn    = "mysql:host=". self::$host . ";dbname=" . self::$database . ";charset=" . self::$charSet;
            $pdo    = new PDO($dsn, self::$username, self::$password);

            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            return $pdo;
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

> phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         verbose="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Test suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

If I try to put my password with my Local MySQL it works but my database is not there. I know I could have imported it but I want to try this one.